# django admin links to OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-admin

I have following models:

```
class OrderData(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()

class Order(models.Model):
    order_data = models.OneToOneField(OrderData)
```

In admin interface at my Order details page i need the OneToOne field to be a link instead of drop list.

I was trying to solve it by writing a custom OrderAdmin:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('order_data',)

    def order_data(self, instance):
        return "<a href=\"/\">index</a>"

    address_report.short_description = "Order_data"
    address_report.allow_tags = True

admin.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

but seems it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

define a widget:

```
class OrderDataLinkWidget(Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        url ="/admin_url_to_use/%s"%value #or use reverse
        return "<a href='%s'>order data</a>"%(url, )
```

use formfield_overrides in admin.py:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.OneToOneField: {'widget': OrderDataLinkWidget},
    }
```

or, define custom admin form if you have more OneToOneField

Answer (score 0):

This one but I use grapelli app:

```
class BankAccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('user', 'bank')
    related_lookup_fields = { 'user': ['user'], 'bank': ['bank'],}
```

If you don't want to use that, you can code it in forms.py not in the admin.py